# IndexController postAction not calling

Tags: magento

my form is below

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('ydg/offredpriceform/index/post')?>" id="make_offer_form" method="post">
```

my namespace is "Ydg" and my module is"Offredpriceform" inside I have index controller 
like this Ydg\Offredpriceform\controllers\IndexController and inside IndexController I have post method and I am calling this from dialogbox form without helper of my module so problem is post action is not calling

Comment: I have not created front template or layout, will it require to call controller action?

Comment: what is the xml in config.xml to add this controller?

Comment: In frontend->routers... Better yet... post the complete config.xml

Comment: <routers>
            <ydg_offredpriceform>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ydg_Offredpriceform</module>
                    <frontName>ydg_offredpriceform</frontName>
                </args>
            </ydg_offredpriceform>
        </routers>

Comment: your url is example.com/ydg_offredpriceform/index/post

Comment: Thanks for your kind response but what should I do to call IndexController action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you want to call is:

```
http://www.examplemagento.com/ydg_offredpriceform/index/post
```

To let magento generate this url, use the following:

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('ydg_offredpriceform/index/post'); ?>
```

Comment: now controller is called but getting this error "Controller file was loaded but class does not exist"

Comment: what is the name of your controllerclass?

Comment: Try finding a tutorial on how to create a controller... Because I dont think you have understood how Magento works yet...

Comment: Your controller class should be something like `class Ydg_Offredpriceform_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {}`

Comment: I have also created controller OfferedpriceformController

Comment: Hey @RichardBernards this is common  "Ydg_offerdpriceform" for all controller I just give you the controller file name sorry...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65377/discussion-between-vijay-sankhat-and-richardbernards).